# Can't find CLion CMake option -G "Visual Studio 15 2017"

Tags: cmake, clion, jetbrains-ide

In CLion `2017.2.1`, I can't figure out how to set the generator `-G "Visual Studio 15 2017"` in the IDE CMake options. The CLion command line always contains `-G "CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles"`.

On command line, I can use `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017"` to compile my code.

How do I set CLion to use the Visual Studio generator?

Note: I am using the [Visual Studio compiler](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2017/02/clion-2017-1-eap-first-steps-to-asm-and-msvc/) in CLion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible in CLion now. It doesn't support other generators. Only NMake Makefiles for MSVC, and usual Makefiles on all other cases.

Comment: but this is a cmake thing, it theoretically shouldn't matter what Clion doesn't support in this regard, *cmake supports it*.

Comment: A nasty side affect of this is that you can't use the LLVM/Clang targets in Windows either.